# leaflet container/layer points

Tags: javascript, maps, leaflet

Trying to make custom map.

Here's simple example http://codepen.io/TrySound/pen/LZxZWR

```
const layerBottomRight = L.point(config.width, config.height);
const containerBottomRight = map.layerPointToContainerPoint(layerBottomRight);
console.log('layer bottom right', layerBottomRight.x, layerBottomRight.y);
console.log('container right bottom', containerBottomRight.x, containerBottomRight.y);
```

The problem is that container and layer points are the same on any zoom which is not what I expect. Am I missing something in configuration?

Comment: This is unclear. How are you checking the container / layer coordinates on different zoom levels?

Comment: By changing zoom in config. Ratio of layer and container coords changes and result should be different. Maybe I don't understand leaflet logic, but this is first user look.

Comment: Container points are pixel coordinates from the top-left corner of the map container. Layer points are pixel coordinates from the top-left corner of the internal pane container. Pixels, not map units. They don't change with the zoom level.

Answer (score 0):

Container always have the same size(Div size), Change for this:

```
console.log('container right bottom', map.getSize().x, map.getSize().y);
```

Comment: I know container size. I need to know where is current bottom right of viewport in layer. But they are always the same.

Comment: @BogdanChadkin I belive that you want something like latlng: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#latlng

Comment: plus check this: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/69124/leaflet-container-coordinates-vs-layer-coordinates